# Linking php form to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, hyperlink

Trying to link my php form to my database but it isn't working. Can anyone find a fault? It keeps giving me a parse error on the 'INSERT INTO' part of the code.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect($localhost,$root,$xxxxxxx);

if (!$link) {
die("Could not connect");
};

print "Connected to the database server";

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($module_evaluation_results, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die("Could not use the database");
};

print "selected a DB";

$result = mysql_query (INSERT INTO module_evaluation_results 
(faculty, date, modulecode, moduletitle, school, modulebookcontent, moduleorganisation, lrcmaterials, moduledifficulty. modulesimilarity, 
contentinteresting, previousknowledge, understoodassessmentrequirements, assessmentmethod, moduleleader, ML_interestforsubject, ML_contentclear, 
ML_appropriateteachingpace,ML_reachableforadvice, ML_helpfulfeedback, lecturer1, L1_interestforsubject, L1_contentclear, 
L1_appropriateteachingpace, L1_reachableforadvice, L1_helpfulfeedback, lecturer2, L2_interestforsubject, L2_contentclear, L2_appropriateteachingpace, 
L2_reachableforadvice, L2_helpfulfeedback, hoursofindependentstudy, overallattendance, bestfeaturesofmodule, improvemodule)

VALUES ($faculty, $date, $modulecode, $moduletitle, $school, $modulebookcontent, $moduleorganisation, $lrcmaterials, $moduledifficulty, 
$modulesimilarity, $contentinteresting, $previousknowledge, $understoodassessmentrequirements, $assessmentmethod, $moduleleader, 
$ML_interestforsubject, $ML_contentclear, $ML_appropriateteachingpace, $ML_reachableforadvice, $ML_helpfulfeedback, $lecturer1, $L1_interestforsubject, 
$L1_contentclear, $L1_appropriateteachingpace, $L1_reachableforadvice, 
$L1_helpfulfeedback, $lecturer2, $L2_interestforsubject, 
$L2_contentclear, $L2_appropriateteachingpace, $L2_reachableforadvice, 
$L2_helpfulfeedback, $hoursofindependentstudy, 
$overallattendance, $bestfeaturesofmodule, $improvemodule));

if (!$result) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

print "run a query against the DB";

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Put some quotation marks around the INSERT query.  In addition, don't use mysql_query.  It is deprecated.  Use mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is there no quotations in your query? copy and paste issue? or is that the error?

i.e.

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO module_evaluation_results 
(faculty, date, modulecode, moduletitle, school, modulebookcontent, moduleorganisation, lrcmaterials, moduledifficulty. modulesimilarity, 
contentinteresting, previousknowledge, understoodassessmentrequirements, assessmentmethod, moduleleader, ML_interestforsubject, ML_contentclear, 
ML_appropriateteachingpace,ML_reachableforadvice, ML_helpfulfeedback, lecturer1, L1_interestforsubject, L1_contentclear, 
L1_appropriateteachingpace, L1_reachableforadvice, L1_helpfulfeedback, lecturer2, L2_interestforsubject, L2_contentclear, L2_appropriateteachingpace, 
L2_reachableforadvice, L2_helpfulfeedback, hoursofindependentstudy, overallattendance, bestfeaturesofmodule, improvemodule)

VALUES ($faculty, $date, $modulecode, $moduletitle, $school, $modulebookcontent, $moduleorganisation, $lrcmaterials, $moduledifficulty, 
$modulesimilarity, $contentinteresting, $previousknowledge, $understoodassessmentrequirements, $assessmentmethod, $moduleleader, 
$ML_interestforsubject, $ML_contentclear, $ML_appropriateteachingpace, $ML_reachableforadvice, $ML_helpfulfeedback, $lecturer1, $L1_interestforsubject, 
$L1_contentclear, $L1_appropriateteachingpace, $L1_reachableforadvice, 
$L1_helpfulfeedback, $lecturer2, $L2_interestforsubject, 
$L2_contentclear, $L2_appropriateteachingpace, $L2_reachableforadvice, 
$L2_helpfulfeedback, $hoursofindependentstudy, 
$overallattendance, $bestfeaturesofmodule, $improvemodule)");
```

### Revised answer :)

This function was on php.net by ddlshack at https://www.php.net/mysql_query I've tested it locally with some changes to reflect your usecase and its working fine perhaps it will help simplify your insert call as well

```
function mysql_insert($table, $inserts) 
{
    $values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($inserts));
    $keys = array_keys($inserts);
       
    return mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');
}
```

Used like so;

```
 mysql_insert(
        'module_evaluation_results', array(
        'col1' => rand(10,100),
        'col2' => 'string1',
        'col3' => 'string2',
        'col4' => rand(10,100),
        'col5' => 'string3',
    ));
```

So mysql_insert( Table name, array(column name, value));

My full php test file is the following

```
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'test-user', 'test-pass');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test", $link);
if (!$db_selected) 
{
    die("Could not use the database");
};

mysql_insert(
    'module_evaluation_results', array(
    'col1' => rand(10,100),
    'col2' => 'string1',
    'col3' => 'string2',
    'col4' => rand(10,100),
    'col5' => 'string3',
)); 

mysql_close($link);

function mysql_insert($table, $inserts) 
{
    $values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($inserts));
    $keys = array_keys($inserts);
       
    return mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');
}
```

I think the problem might be your table name? plus the complexity of the query as written might be some typos
but this code definately works inserts can be run multiple times and is simpler to read and code if that helps

Comment: still needs to change moduledifficulty. modulesimilarity to moduledifficulty, modulesimilarity

Comment: That helped, thank you, but it's still not working. It says - Use of undefined constant localhost - assumed 'localhost''root' and 'password' @duindain

Comment: The most likely cause could be that there are no quotes around your `VALUES` I.e.: `VALUES ($faculty, $date, $modulecode` which should read as `VALUES ('$faculty', '$date', '$modulecode'` etc. etc. @taniakeira

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just tried that but it still can't identify the values.

Comment: How are you defining `$module_evaluation_results` as your table? There's no other mention of it. Unless you meant `module_evaluation_results` without the `$` sign, but I think that's highly unlikely. @taniakeira

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed $module_evaluation_results to "module_evaluation_results" and the same with localhost root and password. Now it's just the values that aren't being identified.

Comment: Do all columns exist and what is your table's name? I don't know what else to tell you. Plus I don't know why you accepted this answer if you're still having problems. It should be up to the person who's given you the answer, that should be troubleshooting this with you, not me. I can't help you anymore than I already have. @taniakeira Good luck.

Comment: Part of the problem is your columns and tablename should be quoted \`column1` as well as the values, this will be solved automatically if you use the function i mention above

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
moduledifficulty. modulesimilarity
```

use

```
moduledifficulty, modulesimilarity
```